# Get last stored value at a given time in influxDB

Tags: influxdb

I'm storing values of my temperature sensors in an `influxDB` database and I'm looking for a special request.
Each sensor sends sensed data when temperature changes with a certain threshold which means that all sensors do not send data at the same time. 
So sensor 1, namely `S1` will send value 1 (`S1_v1`) at instant `t1`. Then `S2` will send `S2_v2` at `t2`, `S3` sends `S3_v3` at `t3`, etc. 
I'd like to have the values of all the sensors at a given time `t` so that at `t2`, the returned value of `S1` will be `S1_v1` (the last stored one).

How can I do that with influxDB please? I hope my request is enough clear.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all your sensor data into one `measurement`.

Then have a `tag` call name to store the sensor's name.

**Example:**

```
> select * from sensors;
name: sensors
time                name value
----                ---- -----
1547100000000000000 s1   500
1547200000000000000 s2   600
1547300000000000000 s3   700
1548000000000000000 s1   900
1548000000000000000 s2   800
1548000000000000000 s3   999
```

To retrieve the latest stored value of all the sensors at a given time range `t` you can do the following;

```
SELECT * FROM sensors 
 WHERE time >= 1547000000000000000 and time <= 1547300000000000000
 GROUP BY "name" order by desc limit 1;
```

**Output:**

```
name: sensors
tags: name=s3
time                value
----                -----
1547300000000000000 700

name: sensors
tags: name=s2
time                value
----                -----
1547200000000000000 600

name: sensors
tags: name=s1
time                value
----                -----
1547100000000000000 500
```

The query above is essentially grouping the data of all your sensors into individual bucket based on your time filter. Then the `ORDER BY DESC` is for sorting them into descending order so that the first row is always the point with greatest time. `Limit 1` is just asking the query engine to return you the top 1 row.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I'd like to have a request where I specify one specific timestamp and get all last stored values at this moment. Not providing a time range. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: Yes. Instead of giving it a range in the filter statement, do only `WHERE time <= t`. where `t` is your time value.